# How do I update partial columns in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a large table in clickhouse, and after adding a column with "alter table add column ed_code String", I want to refresh the column data according to the primary key.  What should I do?   Supplement: Refresh the data for this column alone.   "ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree", need to add all of the fields "insert" again.   "ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree" not according to the "column" to update?

"ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree"& "ReplicatedVersionedCollapsingMergeTree" Can't do it. Ask for help.

such as：

> CREATE TABLE db_name1.tb_name1
> (
> `ed_code` String,
> `dis_code` Int64 ,
> `div_code` Int64 ,
> `div_city` String ,
> `div_code_region` Int64,
> `div_code_dept` Int64 ,
> `dis_code_region` Int64 ,
> `dis_code_city` Int64 ,
> `dis_code_district` Int64,
> .......100 column
> )
> ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{cluster_1shard_s_all}/goldeneye/dim_ed_all_mapping_div', '{replica}', etl_tm)
> primary key ed_code
> ORDER BY (ed_code)
> SETTINGS storage_policy = 'policy_poll', index_granularity = 8192, use_minimalistic_part_header_in_zookeeper = 1;

There are already 1 billion pieces of data in the table above.
Now we need to add  new column :

> alter table db_name1.tb_name1 add column ed_status Int8 comment 'cabinet status[1:on,0:off,2:damage]';

I need to update the "ed_status" column of "db_name1.tb_name1" according to "ed_code"
I can only use all the column

> insert into db_name1.tb_name1 (ed_code,dis_code....  ,ed_status) values(xx,xxx.....  ,xxx)

to update?
Is that a waste of resources?
Why not just

> insert into db_name1.tb_name1 (ed_code,ed_status) values(xx,xxx)

with the primary key and the field to be updated .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use asynchonous mutations

`ALTER TABLE db.table UPDATE SET ed_code=if(primary_key_field=1,XXX,YYY)`

Look at documentation about details:

- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/update
- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/mutations
- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter#mutations

Poll `SELECT * FROM system.mutations WHERE is_done=0 AND database=? AND table=?` for result